# How many slots needs to provide in the flink, If all the server configurations are different?

Tags: apache-flink

I am running flink on the kubernetes.

Following are the configurations of server:

```
server - 1: 4cpu, 16gb RAM
server - 2: 2cpu, 8gb RAM
server - 3: 2cpu, 8gb RAM
```

By using the above configurations how to set the parallelism and slots.  I want to run 3 taskmanger.
Currently I have provided below configurations. Is it correct?

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
parallelism.default: 3
```

As per the understanding each cpu will be treated as 1 slot. should it be like numberOfTaskSlots has to be configure 2, because that is available for 3 taskmanager.

`parallelism.default: 3` because i am using number of taskmanager as 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the parallelism across all of the jobs should match the total number of slots. The slots should each have the same resources available (RAM and cpus). One cpu per slot is just a guideline -- what's appropriate really depends on the job(s) that will be running, and how much work each slot will be doing.

In this case with 2 slots per task manager, and 3 task managers, the cluster can support a total parallelism of 6.

Comment: We are running 4 jobs. Is it relevant If I will increase the slots?

Comment: Six slots isn’t much for 4 jobs. You might want to set the default parallelism to one, and only raise it for the one or two jobs you’ll want to take the remaining two slots. Or configure more slots.

Comment: Can I increase the slots from 2 to 4 and parallelism also 3 to 6 ? so that we will get more parallelism. is it recommended?

Comment: The default parallelism simply establishes a default for jobs started in the cluster that don't override the default. But if you expect to run four jobs with a parallelism of 6, you'll need 24 slots in total.

Comment: for increasing slots there is only one option to increase the cpu process? .sorry If I am not wrong you are telling no matter how many 'taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots' you are putting in the configuration file it will take the default one which in my case is the 2 cpu process?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. You can put what you want for taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots and that value will be used (unless overridden on the command line). Keep in mind that if you make it too large, at some point you won't have enough memory, or enough CPU to avoid constant backpressure. Also be aware that on kubernetes it is generally recommended to run more, smaller task managers, each with one slot.

Comment: got it.. Thanks for your valuable answer @David.